# How to import JSON by pandas from data.world?

Tags: python, json, pandas, database

I am new to this and have no idea why my code doesn't work.
I want to read json data from: https://data.world/cnoza/cryptocurrencies
I've tried it by link:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('https://query.data.world/s/tcjtnx4d2kjaujslprdlgnr72wwoue')
```

And also tried uploading the file:

```
df = pd.read_json("EUR.json")
```

Some kind of error occurs

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Thanks!
Thanks to @Chris Happy for the clue
The solution that helped me:

```
import json
with open('EUR.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ["data"])
```

Comment: Thanks to @Chris Happy for the clue  
The solution that helped me:  
    import json
    with open('EUR.json') as data_file:    
        data = json.load(data_file)

    df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ["data"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas only handles JSON in a 2D format, but the cryptocurrency data is in a multi-dimensional form.

Instead, use [pd.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) like:

```py
import json
with open('EUR.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path = ["data"])
```

<sup>Updated with @sleshworld's fix.</sup>